# remainder when $43$ divides $32002^{4200}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

what will be the remainder when $43$ divides $32002^{4200}$??

what I did is:
$32002\equiv10 \pmod{43}$,
how to proceed further?

Comment: See [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Further to what you observed, $10^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod {43}$ (why?)

Comment: why $10^{42}$?? what about 32002??

Comment: dint get you.....????

Comment: For the reason you figured out above: 32002 and 10 are equivalent (mod 43), which means anywhere you might add, multiply, or use as the base (but not the power) of exponentiation, you can use 10 instead of 32002.  ...but in reality, $anything^{42}\equiv 1\pmod {43}$. (well, anything as long as it's coprime to 43, so not 0; 43 is prime though so that's it)

Comment: You already mentioned $32002 \equiv 10 \pmod {43}$.  Now use $a \equiv b \pmod p \implies a^n \equiv b^n \pmod p$.  For a proof, notice $(a-b) | (a^n-b^n)$

Comment: Fortunately for us 43 is prime!

Comment: ohkk..got it..so the answer is 1..

Answer (score 0):

From [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) (here [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) is sufficient, however...)
$$\left(\gcd(a,b) = 1 \right)\Longrightarrow a^{\varphi(b)} \equiv 1 \pmod{b}$$

Where $\varphi$ is [totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function. Here $\gcd(43, 3202) = 1 \wedge \varphi(43) = 42$ (43 is prime, so all number $\lbrace1,2,...,42\rbrace$ are coprime). So,

$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
\gcd(43,3202)= 1~~ \Longrightarrow~~&3202^{\varphi(43)} &\equiv 1 \pmod{43} \Leftrightarrow \\
&3202^{42} & \equiv 1 \pmod{43} \end{split}\end{align*}$$

Assume that $3202^{4200} = 3202^{42\cdot100} = \left(3202^{42}\right)^{100}  = \left(3202^{\varphi(43)}\right)^{100} \cdot 3202^{0}$ and by simple transformations, obtain:

$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
3202^{4200} &\equiv \left(3202^{\varphi(43)}\right)^{100} &\pmod{43} \Longleftrightarrow \\
3202^{4200} &\equiv \left(1\right)^{100} &\pmod{43}\Longleftrightarrow \\
3202^{4200} &\equiv 1 & \pmod{43}\end{split}\end{align*}$$

Thus, the number you are looking for [is 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3202%5E4200%20mod%2043).