# Find $700^{1734} \mod{347}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$700^{1734} \mod{347}$$

I know how this could be calculated if I had $376$ in the exponent, using Fermat's theorem. But I have no idea how to approach this problem. What theorem's are appropriate to refer to?

Comment: $700 \equiv 6 \mod 347$, so $700^{1734}\equiv 6^{1734} \mod 347$

Comment: Note that $1734=(346)(5)+4$.

Comment: See [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 1):

$347$ is prime, so you can use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).
$$347 \nmid a \Longrightarrow a^{347-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{347}$$

Note that
$700^{1734} = 700^{1730}\cdot 700^{4} =
\left(700^{346}\right)^{5} \cdot 700^{4}$.
And from Fermat's theorem
$$\left(700^{346}\right)^{5} \cdot 700^{4} \equiv (1)^5 \cdot 700^{4} \pmod{347}$$

And now obvious steps $700^4 \equiv 6^4 \pmod{347} \wedge 6^4 \equiv 255 \pmod{347}$, so number you are looking for is 255.

However, if $347$ will be just coprime with $700$ (assume $347$ isn't prime) than you can use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). Of course this theorem works here too ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1016897/186012)). In fact Fermat's little theorem is just a special case of Euler's totient theorem, but using whole is a little bit triumph of form over content.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $347$ is a prime.

Also, $700\equiv 6\pmod{347}$

By eulers $6^{\phi(347)}\equiv 1\pmod{347}$ where $\phi$ is the Euler's phi function.